# Force exe to run in NON ELEVATED mode from Task scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, 32-bit, windows-task-scheduler, elevation, elevated

I am admin user. I have 32 bit exe which I have scheduled it from task scheduler to run at every night. Though it is running in elevated mode. How do I force it to run in non elevated mode. I did try to uncheck "Run with highest privileges" but did not help.

Comment: Create a new user that is not admin, and schedule to run it through that user.

Comment: Yes I tried it but that way exe is not running correctly(not the permission issues). In other words, if admin manually runs it (non elevated) it is working fine. I tried to use

run-app-as-non-admin.bat

Set ApplicationPath="C:\Program Files\SomeApp\testapp.exe"
cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" %ApplicationPath%"


but not working either from task scheduler when I set this bat file as action

Comment: Is the task doing something on a network share that the new user does not have access to?

Comment: No it is all local. 
when I use __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER , I think task scheduler always in elevated mode and and hence causing exe to be run in elevated mode too.. so I am not sure this is going to work at all

Comment: why are you using runasinvoker anyway? you can just set the task to run as a different user non-elevated and it will run as if you double-click the exe. No need to use all the settings you set

Comment: Yes but exe is having issue when it is running under standard user. I tried to give full permission on the exe for standard user and is not working like just admin double click work.. not sure in backend what exe is trying to access..

Comment: When your exe only runs fine as admin, why don't you want to run it as admin? Probably it is useful to create a new question with details of "having issue when it is running under standard user".

Comment: I am using c# console application to connect to QB via SDK. I have scheduled the console application on task scheduler under admin user account. Task scheduler is running both app and QB in elevated mode. Though this seems to work when no other user is connected to server and logged into QB. When other users open QuickBooks(Multi User mode), app is having an issue and error says "Could not start QuickBooks". I did try to set UAC level to never notify but did not help..... my original question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526681/qb-sdk-error-could-not-start-quickbooks

Comment: So basically the issue is not with the task scheduler or your own code, but with launching multiple instances of QuickBooks at the same time? What does the QuickBooks support team say about this?

Comment: I asked the similar question in QuickBooks Forums too no answers. usually it is well known that QB SDK is not that stable in terms of connection but people knows workarounds and I do not.